# HTML Purifier for webmail

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

I'm working on small webmail client. For safely embedding html I want to use HTML Purifier (BTW: it's a good idea?).

I checked it with several emails and some problems. One email (from Google) is having something like this:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="4%">
<td width="92%" style="padding-top:18px; padding-bottom:10px; opacity:0.7">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<td width="30%">
<img style="display:inline-block;" height="26" src="https://www.gstatic.com/local/guides/email/images/photo-impact/googlelogo_light_clr-f040d5d9.png">
<td>
<td width="70%" style="text-align:right">
</td>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Converts to:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td width="4%">
</td><td width="92%" style="padding-top:18px;padding-bottom:10px;opacity:.7;">
</td><td width="30%">
<img style="display:inline-block;" height="26" src="https://www.gstatic.com/local/guides/email/images/photo-impact/googlelogo_light_clr-f040d5d9.png" alt="googlelogo_light_clr-f040d5d9.png">
</td><td>
</td><td width="70%" style="text-align:right;">
</td>
</tr></table>
```

I don't know why it remove second `<table>` tag (also it close wrong `<td>` and removes `<tbody>`). Is it possible to change HTML Purifier to make it work for those situations?

Comment: Can you share your current configuration settings for HTML Purifier? Running your code through the demo on the site doesn't remove the `<tbody>` tag. What happens if you turn on CollectErrors in your code - what errors do you get? :)

Comment: Sorry, indeed `<tbody>` isn't removed (don't ask ;-)) I'm using `mews/purifier` for Laravel with default configuration. I think that htmlpurifier removes second table because of compliance with standard (in example mail we have table in td) but is it possible to disable this function?

Comment: Is this it? https://github.com/mewebstudio/Purifier/blob/master/config/purifier.php - if so, I'm confused, `table` isn't even in `HTML.Allowed` and should be stripped completely. I'm unfamiliar with Laravel, but I'm afraid we do need more information. Can you expand the settings to include `CoreCollectErrors => true`, then use `$mewsPurifier->getInstance()->context->get('ErrorCollector');` to get the error collector and use `$errorCollector->getHTMLFormatted($mewsPurifier->getConfig());` to get the errors? (You may have to make `getConfig()` public for the duration of the test.)